# Randomly select remaining divs Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I have three divs with the attribute `row`. When the page loads I want to randomly select one of the divs and apply the class `.show`. From here, when the document is clicked I want one of the divs out of the remaining two divs to be randomly selected and have the class `.show` applied to it. When the document is clicked again, the last remaining div showed have `.show` applied to it. Now all three divs have the class `.show`. If the document is clicked again visual cycle should be restart so that only one randomly selected div has the class `.show`.

I've laid out (as a javascript novice) my approach but I don't know how to keep track of the `rowArray` which records which divs are remaining (the divs that DONT have the class `.show`) at each stage of the counter.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I have attached a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6t49yu2p/4/) with comments.

```js
var selector = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
var rowArray = [0, 1, 2];
var counter = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    counter++

    $('#cnt').find("div[row=" + selector +"]").addClass('show');
    var newrowArray = rowArray.splice(selector, 1);

    $(document).on("click", function() {
        counter++
        if (counter ==1 ) {

        } else if (counter == 2) {

        } else {
            counter = 1;

        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cnt">
    <div row="0"></div>
    <div row="1"></div>
    <div row="2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("div[row]:not(.show)")` will return the row div(s) that do not have the class `show` applied to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a function that selects all the elements that do not have show class, using this list select a randomIndex and then randomly add class show to one these elements. You can all this function on page load and from click on document.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

function selectDiv(){
   var notSelectedDivs = $("div[row]:not(.show)");
   
   if(!notSelectedDivs.length){
       $('.show').removeClass('show');
       notSelectedDivs = $("div[row]:not(.show)");
   }
   var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * notSelectedDivs.length));
   $(notSelectedDivs[randomIndex]).addClass('show');
}


$(document).on("click", function() {
    selectDiv();
});
selectDiv();
});
```

```css
.show{
color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cnt">
<div row="0">1</div>
<div row="1">2</div>
<div row="2">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer. works great